# accessing previously included (required) class methods from an ajax file

Tags: php, ajax, class, methods

i'm a php novice, and i'm wondering the best way to go about using previously defined class methods from a front facing ajax file.  i trolled through 50 or more of the top questions looking for something similar to this, so my apologies if this has been asked before.

my project is set up using a front controller which calls initialize.php, which then includes all the class files i've made for this project thus far, whether those class methods/properties will be needed now or not (if this is super bad then someone please tell me an alternative :[[).  so basically, for every request made on this site initialize is called, all of those classes are defined and two are instantiated immediately, those two being the classes i use for the database and sessioning/login stuff.

i've been doing this in my ajax files:

```
<?php
// login.ajax.php
require_once 'initialize.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$remember = $_POST['remember'];

global $session; // this is instantiated right away every time
$login = $session->login($email, $password);

echo json_encode($login);
?>
```

recent complications are now making me rethink this approach.  constantly loading initialize seems really wasteful, but including/requiring just the necessary class files would be a pain in the ass at best.  in this example i'd need to include session, which would also need two other classes to perform this login.

Comment: I prefer autoloading as suggesting in the answers. However, I have worked on a pretty large site where we did exactly what you're doing and loaded everything. However, we were relying on the APC cache. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may wish to use **PHP autoloading mechanism**.

To see some details, please go to [the PHP autoloading documentation](http://php.net/autoload). You can read there that:

> Many developers writing object-oriented applications create one PHP source file per-class definition. One of the biggest **annoyances is having to write a long list of needed includes** at the beginning of each script (one for each class).
>
> In PHP 5, this is no longer necessary. You may **define an __autoload function** which is automatically called in case you are trying to use a class/interface which hasn't been defined yet. By calling this function the scripting engine is given a last chance to load the class before PHP fails with an error.

Within your initialization file (or separate one, depending on your design decisions) just define `__autoload()` function that will be used to include required files:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include_once $class_name . '.php';
}
```

This should solve the issue / need of multiple requirement / inclusion declarations - from now on, when you instantiate some class and it is not available, newly defined function (`__autoload()`) will be called to include necessary files.

Comment: it seems that you're saying to rely on autoloading for my ajax files?  if this is the case, is autoloading reliable enough and does it make sense in terms of cost to just rely solely on that instead of worry about loading at all?

Comment: Yes, it is reliable - it is used in multiple PHP frameworks. Just make sure it is not too complex (eg. just define list of available files so you do not need to search your filesystem to find them). But the most efficient solution is, I believe, storing all the necessary code (and **only** necessary code) within single file (the one that is called). But I believe you may not need such thing and it may be better for you to just use autoloading.

Answer (score 1):

For being a novice you have a decent grasp on more advanced terms such as controller and how to properly initialize your application (i.e. bootstrapping).

My projects over the last few years have been built on the Symfony framework, and it does much the same thing you are describing; the controller determines the environment (dev or prod etc) then will bootstrap the framework based on configuration files.

The difference between your approach and Symfony's approach is that Symfony takes advantage of what's known as [autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). Symfony will parse certain directories looking for class files, creating an array of any classes found, then it writes the arrays to a flatfile so subsequent requests don't incur the overhead of traversing the directories again. So now when I work on the application and I need access to a file I simply make the call and PHP knows where to find it thanks autoloading.

You could also take it one step further and name space your classes, not to be confused with [PHP Namespacing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php). What I mean is you base your class names on their location within the file-system. Obviously you won't want to include the full file-path, but start with a root dir then work from it. Namespacing also makes it much easier to find the file.

Example of class name-spacing with autoloading:

```
 // /home/mpurcell/projects/core/lib/CoreLib/Api/Database.php
 // I told php to use /home/mpurcell/projects/core/lib as my root by adding it to include path, and registered the CoreLib_Api_ with the autoloader
 // So my class would look like this:

 class CoreLib_Api_Database
 {
     ...
 }     

 // /home/mpurcell/projects/app/myAwesomeApp/makeMoneyMoney.php

 // As long as the autoloader has been initialized, I can make calls without having to require files
 CoreLib_Api_Database::getDbo($dboKey);
```

If you want the autoloading capability without having to use it within a framework context, I'd suggest the Zend Framework, more specifically [Zend_Loader_Autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html).

Lol sorry if this a little more than you were expecting, but you asked a good question.